# How can I color a line graph by grouping the variables in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have produced a line graph something that looks like this

[image: Generated using ggplot2]

I have the data set of 50 countries and its GDP for last 10 years.
Sample data:

```
Country variable value  
China   Y2007    3.55218e+12
USA     Y2007    1.45000e+13
Japan   Y2007    4.51526e+12
UK      Y2007    3.06301e+12
Russia  Y2007    1.29971e+12 
Canada  Y2007    1.46498e+12
Germany Y2007    3.43995e+12 
India   Y2007    1.20107e+12
France  Y2007    2.66311e+12
SKorea  Y2007    1.12268e+12
```

I generated the line graph using the code

```
GDP_lineplot = ggplot(data=GDP_linechart, aes(x=variable,y=value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "GDP(USD in Trillions)", 
                     breaks = c(0.0e+00,5.0e+12,1.0e+13,1.5e+13), 
                     labels = c(0,5,10,15)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Years", labels = c(2007,"",2009,"",2011,"",2013,"",2015))
```

The idea is to make the graph look like this.
[image: How can I plot the colors]

I tried adding

```
group=country, color = country
```

It outputs coloring all the countries.

How can I color the countries with top 4 and the rest?

PS: I am still naive with R.

Comment: `ggplot(data=GDP_linechart,aes(x=variable,y=value, color=Country)) + ...` should do the trick.

Comment: Yes it does! But It aligns 50 different colors since I have 50 countries .

I need the top 4 countries with different colors and the rest of the countries with Gray.(refer this https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAhZM.png) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By plotting subsets, the other groups aren't included in the colour legend on the right. The alternative approach below manipulates factor levels and uses a customized color scale to overcome this.

## Preparing data

It is assumed that `GDP_long` contains the data in long format. This is in line with the data shown by the OP (`GDP_lineplot`, but see Data section below for differences). To manipulate factor levels, the `forcats`package is used (and `data.table`).

```
library(data.table)
library(forcats)
# coerce to data.table, reorder factors by values in last = most actual year
setDT(GDP_long)[, Country := fct_reorder(Country, -value, last)]
# create new factor which collapses all countries to "Other" except the top 4 countries
GDP_long[, top_country := fct_other(Country, keep = head(levels(Country), 4))]
```

## Create plot

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(GDP_long, aes(Year, value/1e12, group = Country, colour = top_country)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line(size = 1) + theme_bw() + ylab("GDP(USD in Trillions)") +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Country", 
                      values = c("green3", "orange", "blue", "red", "grey"))
```

[image]

The chart is now quite similar to the expected result. The lines of the top 4  countries are displayed in different colours while the other countries are displayed in grey but do appear in the colour legend to the right.

Note that the `group`aesthetic is still needed so that a single line is plotted for each country while `colour` is controlled by the levels of `top_country`.

## Data

The data set is too large to be reproduced here (even with `dput()`). The structure

```
str(GDP_long)
'data.frame':   1763 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Country: chr  "Afghanistan" "Albania" "Algeria" "Andorra" ...
 $ Year   : int  2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 ...
 $ value  : num  9.84e+09 1.07e+10 1.35e+11 4.01e+09 6.04e+10 ...
```

is similar to OP's data with the exception that the `variable` column already  is converted to an integer column `year`. This will give a nicely formatted x-axis without additional effort.

Comment: You nailed it! Thank you! The exact answer I was looking for. 

I was skeptical about my data. Because in my data
Two of the variables were factors. Thought I would get some error. However, It went through. It is a good lesson for me.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies I missed the part about only coloring a subset of the countries... in the geom_line calls you can add the subsetting that suits your needs.

```
df <- data.frame(Country=rep(LETTERS[1:10], each=5),
    Year=rep(2007:2011, length.out=10), 
    value=rnorm(50))

ggplot(df) +
 geom_line(data=df[21:50, ], aes(x=Year, y=value, group=Country), color="#999999") +
 geom_line(data=df[1:20, ], aes(Year, y=value, color=Country))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! for the response. you gave geom_line(data = df[1:20,]... Where the letters are in order. but in mydata set the countries are not in order. the first column must be with 10 variables of china and 10 US ("10" since its  I have the data of 10 years)

I should manipulate the data now. How can I do it. looks complicated.

Comment: You can subset like so `GDP_linechart[GDP_linehcart$Coutnry %in% c("Japan","China", "United States", "Germany"), ]` and `GDP_linechart[!GDP_linehcart$Coutnry %in% c("Japan","China", "United States", "Germany"), ]`