# can't find a solution for color the month in line graph in r

Tags: r

I would like to create a line graph with the following colors

yellow for january, february and march

red for april, may and june

green for july, august and september

blue for october, november and december

I have the following code:

```
temperature <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Year= c(1998,1998,1998,1998,1998,1998,1998,1998,1998,1998,1998,1998,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002),
  Month = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
  Temperature = c(5,6,7,12,15,16,27,28,22,10,11,6,6,6,7,13,16,15,25,26,24,12,11,4,5,6,7,12,15,17,28,30,22,10,11,7,7,7,7,12,18,17,25,24,20,3,3,4,5,6,7,12,15,16,27,28,22,10,11,6),
  check.names = FALSE
)

temperature$date = as.Date(paste(temperature$Year, temperature$Month,1), format = "%Y %m %d")

ggplot(temperature,
       aes(
         x = date,
         y = Temperature
        )) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("Time series") +
scale_x_date(date_breaks = "year", date_labels = "%Y", date_minor_breaks = "month") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Temperature")
```

But I don't know how to color the month and create a legend next to the line graph. Could someone please help?

The line is subdivided in different colors based on months

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I color a line graph by grouping the variables in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43286181/how-can-i-color-a-line-graph-by-grouping-the-variables-in-r)

Comment: I used that, but did not solve my problem

Comment: The problem is, there is only one line, but the line should have different colors. In this example, where you send, there were different lines

Comment: Ah.  I see.  I will withdraw my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, to allow control of the colours with standard `scale_colour_xxxx` calls, you can override the default grouping defined by `colour=Month` with `group=1`.  This will allow use of a legend.

```
ggplot(temperature,
       aes(
         x = date,
         y = Temperature,
         colour=as.factor(Month),
         group=1
       )) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("Time series") +
  scale_x_date(
    date_breaks = "year", 
    date_labels = "%Y", 
    date_minor_breaks = "month"
  ) +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Temperature")
```

[image]

For a continuous "flow" of colours across `Month`, use `colour=Month`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how elegant (especially the part regarding ggplot) my approach is, but I used `seas::mkseas()` in the past to determine the season given in datetime objects. In combination with color initialization, one way to solve this might look like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(seas)

temperature$season <- mkseas(temperature$date, width="JFM")

colors <- c("JFM" = "yellow",
            "AMJ" = "red",
            "JAS" = "green",
            "OND" = "blue")

ggplot(temperature,
       aes(
         x = date,
         y = Temperature
       )) +
  geom_line(col = colors[temperature$season]) +
  ggtitle("Time series") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "year", date_labels = "%Y", date_minor_breaks = "month") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Temperature")
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. Pay attention to the minor fix edited above - using `width="JFM"` now instead of `width="DJF"`.